# How to configure sonarqube?

Tags: findbugs, pmd, sonarqube

How can we configure sonarqube for a java 1.4 project?

I am looking for detailed step by step guide in setting up Sonarqube (even for any java version would so as I am trying to learn).

I tried looking at the documentation but was a bit unclear on how to start and set it up.

Ps: I am trying to set up findbugs, pmd etc to my project. So any insight into these also appreciated.

I am trying to do something like this for the first time so requesting all to please share any links/information/videos.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade and precisely detail what step is not clear.

Comment: Appreciate your reply and sorry for the delay, I tried the steps mentioned in the doc. I was stuck on step 5 where it says analyze.

Comment: Continuation: It started up sonar alright but there were no projects to check. The main point is that if i want to configure sonar for a new projects what all things i should do? please bare with my silly questions. thanks

Comment: What the error when you run cd C:\sonar-examples\projects\languages\java\sonar-runner\java-sonar-runner-simple
C:\sonar-runner\bin\sonar-runner.bat ?

Comment: Thanks a lot David, i got it working... I am able to analyze ... How to configure for an existing project. how to make it point to my project. thanks